# How to handle client is offline problem in javscript?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, client

When the internet connection is good my website works fine but when the internet connection goes down firebase return an error called "Client is Offline".
Also sometimes I get problems like -->

[2022-08-04T10:42:54.098Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.7): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We were experiencing this issue with slower (although functioning) internet connections. The only thing that fixed this was adding `experimentalForceLongPolling: true` to our config. You can read about this [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Settings#optional-experimentalforcelongpolling) and [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1674). We struggled with this for weeks so hope this helps.